# Postsharp 3 .1adds .net 4.5 dependency when building a .net 4.0 project?

Tags: .net, postsharp

I have a solution where all projects are build against .net framework 4.0 and we cannot use 4.5 because we need to support Windows XP.
For some reason, when I add Postsharp the resulting build cannot run without .net 4.5 and as far as I see from the build output I see this message:

9>  : message : PostSharp 3.1 [3.1.27.0, 32 bit, CLR 4.5, Release] complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings, processed in 804 ms

Anyone had this and found a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This message only tells that PostSharp compiler itself runs in CLR 4.5 when processing your assembly. But your project is still being built to run with .NET 4.0, or any other [supported framework](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/target-frameworks) you select as your target framework.